# Ruby call next on an enumerator from an external method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

I'm writing some DSL and I'd like to have a repurposable method that yields to a block and traps any exceptions.

Example:

```
def trap_exception(&block)
  yield
rescue StandardError => e
  log "Error: #{e.message}"
  next
end
```

I'd then use it like this:

```
# items is an array
items.each do |item|
  trap_exception do
    # something that might raise an exception. If so, pass to the next item in array
  end
end
```

This is going to raise an error because `next` is not being called within an enumerable.

I'm looking to keep the code within the `trap_exception` block as clean as possible. I'll also be using this method in a number of different places so I'm trying to minimize code duplication as much as possible.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why you need the next method here which is not needed completely. because on exception it will return your message and move to next enum. Also a block passing to your param is not important as ruby did that by default.

Comment: you won't need a block passing here in the method defination.
```def trap_exception```

Comment: Are you saying that in an each loop, a raised exception causes `next` to be called by default? My understanding was that the exception returns from the loop.

Comment: when you are rescueing by (rescue StandardError => e
  log "Error: #{e.message}") that won't get raise any error to break the loop and will iterate to next iteration.

Comment: just because its the last block of your each iteration inside block